# Difficulties with Preg_Match for steam64 validation

Tags: php, preg-match, steam

I have indeed searched the forum and google for a bit. To no avail. I wrote the following:

```
     $steamInfo = $_POST['steam64'];
       if($steamInfo != preg_match('/7656119[0-9]{10}/i', $steamInfo)){
          echo "Incorrect Steam64";
            die();
     }
```

and this works on 1 part of my website using a different set up of ifs / ifelse for an entirely different reason. This time, however, when I enter steam64 no matter what it returns echo. Basically; I need this to tell the user they need the correct steam 64 , I've tried the following as well , which is a slight variation;

```
if(!preg_match('/7656119[0-9]{10}/i', $_POST['Steam']) ) {
  echo "Incorrect";
}
```

Again, no luck. I also tried storing preg_match as a variable and still nothing lol. Looking for some guidance on how to proceed to have this check for a steam64 and not accept anything else.

Thanks!

Comment: what is `$steamInfo` value?

Comment: `preg_match` returns a boolean, true if there're some matches, false otherwise.

Comment: Is it `$_POST['Steam']` or `$_POST['Steam64']`? And what is the content?

Comment: Hey - sorry, I had changed the post variable. Essentially, it needs to be a steam64 id (random ex: 76561198362458043)